# Clustering method. Choice variables when sum of variables is 1 on each observation

Tags: variables, cluster-analysis

There are 3 variables are x, and z=1-(x+y). ( x>=0, y>=0, z>=0 )

Data are like below.

O(1)= (x1,y1,z1)

O(2)= (x2,y2,z2)

...

O(n)= (xn,yn,zn)

I thought that z is not necessary to express each observation because z is determined by x and y.

So, I did clustering this data with x and y. 
And also did clustering same data with x, y and z, too.

The results are different. 
Because the distances in 2D and 3D are not equal.  (It changed.)

(Yes, Of course, the distances 2D and 3D are not equivalent.)

But, What is the right way do clustering in this case?

Do I have to use x and y?  Or, do I have to use x, y and z? Why?

Please someone help me. Thank you in advance!

Below is R code.

```
############
x <- sample(c(0:100), 100, replace = T)
y <- sample(c(0:100), 100, replace = T)
z <- 200 - (x+y)
xyz <- cbind(x,y,z)
xyz <- xyz/200 # z=1-(x+y)
xy <- zyz[,-3] 

require(fpc)
(xy.pamk <- pamk(xy))
plot(xy,col=xy.pamk$pamobject$clustering)

(xyz.pamk <- pamk(xyz))
require(rgl)
plot3d(xyz,col=xyz.pamk$pamobject$clustering,xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1), zlim=c(0,1))

##############
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your theory that you don't need z, because it can be computed from x and y is flawed.

If it were that way, then x,y and x,z and y,z would all give the same result.

But the algorithms don't assume x+y+z=1. They won't assume `x*x+y*y+z*z=1` either or other dependencies of features.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right. x,y and x,z and y,z would notl give the same result. If i want to cluster some shops by customer age portion such as  under 20's(v1), 20's(v2), and over 20's(v3).  Then always the sum of variables is 1. (for example, v1=0.2, v2=0.3, then v3=0.5). I thought that v1 and v2 are sufficent to cluster shops. But it is not.